# Mesh distortion on human rigged model

Tags: mesh, rigging

I rigged a human model that I have purchased, and the mesh is slightly deformed on some body parts as per seen on the screenshots attached, is there any way to avoid this... [image]

Comment: do you mean that when you move the bone it is not deformed the way you want? In that case you need to give some correction in Weight Paint mode

Comment: The movement is fine, but the lines that you see on the lower belly and legs is the mesh distorting slightly when I move the leg and some other parts of the body as well... Do you see what I mean ?
I can't seem to be able to add more screenshots of the mesh itself to my post...

Comment: it looks like a high-poly mesh with a clear separation between the vertex groups, no?

Comment: Wonder what weight map of that bone looks like but it is definitely sharp change from value 1 to 0 on way too high-poly mesh body. Due to it, those polys under line are moving too much and poly over the line are not moving at all. That creates that line, if you need to fix it, take your weight paint, set some 0.2 values in weight and strength and paint over that line, maybe even lower and it could dissapear if I guessed right... Also I can see more of those lines on bicep, chest and mid of thigh